# Find the smallest $n$ such that $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups

> Let us consider the group $A=\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$. Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $A$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$.

**My thought.**
Since $o(A)=8$ then $n\geq 4$.
If $n=4$, then $8$ will divide $24$, but how to make sure whether it has an abelian subgroup of order $8$ or not since $A$ is abelian.

Any help.

Comment: Note on the other hand that (like all groups) $A$ acts faithfully by permutation on itself, so $A \subset S_A \cong S_{\#A} = S_6$. An old qualifying exam from my graduate program included the problem of determining this $n$ for all five groups of order $8$ up to isomorphism. It's quite a nice problem so you might like to attempt the other groups after tackling this case. IIRC the $Q_8$ case can be found as a question elsewhere here.

Comment: $\#A=8$, not $6$.

Comment: Well, it's not hard to believe that $\langle (12)(34)(56) \rangle \cong A$, but showing that $S_6$ is minimal, if it even is, is the tricky part.

Comment: Well how to find this $n$ any hints @Travis

Comment: @GregMartin Oops, thanks for spotting the typo. I managed to conflate the intended hint and pjs36's.

Comment: @learnmore Since we know that $4 \leq n \leq 6$, it's not too inefficient to proceed naively. For any such isomorphism $\phi$, $\phi(1, 0, 0)$ must have order $2$. In $S_4$ there are only two conjugacy classes whose elements have that order, with representatives $(12)$ and $(12)(34)$, so by conjugation we can assume that $\phi(1, 0, 0)$ is one of those. Now, $\phi(0, 1, 0)$ must be an element of order $2$ that commutes with $\phi(1, 0, 0)$. Which elements in $S_4$ commute with $(12)$? Which commute with $(12)(34)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The smallest $n$ is $6$:
1. $A$ is isomorphic to $\langle(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)\rangle$.
2. For $n=4,5$ the only subgroup of order $8$ which $S_n$ does contain is the dihedral group $D_4$ (and its conjugates, being a $2$-Sylow subgroup).

Comment: how do you know the subgroups of $S_4/S_5$ ?

Comment: @learnmore As I said, it's about the subgroups with $8$ elements of $S_4/S5$. It's well known that $D_4$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$ and thus it's a $2$-Sylow subgroup. It's also isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_5$ (since $S_4\subset S_5$), and a $2$-Sylow subgroup in $S_5$, too. But all $2$-Sylow subgroups are conjugated (hence isomorphic).

Answer (score 0):

Note :

- $n\geq 4$ as you observed correctly.
- If $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$, then all elements in $H$ has to have order $2$. So all the elements in $H$ are either $2$ cycles or product of $2$ Cycles. Now, note that if $H$ contains a $2$ -cycle, then it has to be disjoint. (Why?) Think of an example. What if $H$ contains $(1\ 2)$ and $(2\ 3)$?
- So we infer that our subgroup $H$ contains only disjoint $2$ cycles and product of disjoint $2$ cycles.
- We now rule out the case $n=4$. Suppose $H$ contains the two cycle $(1 \ 2)$ Then $H = \{e, (1 \ 2), (3,\ 4), (1\ 2)( 3\ 4)\}$. Try out oter possibilities and see that $|H|=4$ always so $H \not\cong \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.
- By the same reasoning you can rule out $n=5$ as well.
- For $n=6$, we can construct $H$ in the following way.  $H=\{ e, (1\ 2), (3\ 4), (5,\ 6), (1\ 2)(3\ 4), (1\ 2)(5\ 6), (3\ 4)(5\ 6), (1\ 2)(3\ 4)(5\ 6)\}$
- Now to prove $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ note that any abelian group of order $8$ has to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. The first two can't happen since there is no element of order $8$ and $4$ in $H$.